# Unsplash object method available from the console but not from the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

This one baffles me. I've banged my head on it for a couple of weeks now and am getting nowhere. Sorry if it's obvious, I'm still a rails newbie ish...

The app is making an API call to the Unsplash pictures service.

As such the application_helper has the following method:

```
def show_photo(size)
 @photo = Unsplash::Photo.random(query:"cars")[:urls][size.to_sym]
end
```

the view has the following:

```
 <%= image_tag(show_photo('small'), height: "220", width:"220") %>
```

And that displays fine.

The issue is when I want to pull some other methods from the oject. I've added another method in the application helped like this:

```
def show_author
  @photo.user.name
end
```

and the corresponding view:
     Photo by: <%= show_author %>

I then get this error:
    undefined method `user' for #

However when calling the method in the Rails console it works fine:

```
@photo = Unsplash::Photo.random(query:"cars")
=> #<Unsplash::Photo:0x00000004fcf950 @attributes=#<OpenStruct id="CKeoh-
    90U3E", created_at="2017 .......

2.3.0 :003 > @photo.user.name
 => "Florian Schneider"
```

What do I need to do to have the user.name available in the view?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Rodolphe

Comment: Would appreciate if you would respond to the answers posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@photo` is not the photo, it looks like you're calling some meta-data on @photo with `[:urls][size.to_sym]` and you can't call `.user` on top of that meta-data.

You're essentially saying `Unsplash::Photo.random(query:"cars")[:urls][size.to_sym].user`

You might want to do the following:

```
def photo
 @photo ||= Unsplash::Photo.random(query:"cars")
end

def resized_photo(size)
 photo[:urls][size.to_sym]
end

def photo_author_name
  photo.user.name
end
```

btw `@photo ||=` is memoizing the API call so you're not making the same call multiple times.

Comment: theartofbeing, Thank you for your answer, this working absolutely fine! And it totally makes sense...Sorry for the late answer but I was away from my Mac for profesional reasons!